# Does python have a predicate to test that row of a matrix are sorted?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to check that a sequence of *N* numpy vectors of integers is [lexicographically ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).  All the vectors in the sequence have shape 1 × 2.  (The value of *N* is big, so I want to avoid sorting this sequence if it is already sorted.)

Does Python, or numpy, already offer a predicate to perform such a test?

(It would not be hard to roll my own, but I prefer to use built-in tools if they exist.)

Comment: Give us a small example.  What do you mean by 'lexicographic' order?  Order first on one element of each vector, and then on the second?

Comment: @hpaulj: I added a link to the relevant Wikipedia page; lex order is Python's default sort order for tuples and strings.  The answer to your second question is basically 'yes'.  More precisely, those pairs whose first elements are equal are ordered according to their second element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use np.diff and np.any:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3,1], [3, 4, 5]])
diff =  np.diff(A, axis=0)
print np.all(diff>=0, axis=0)
```

Comment: I don't think this tests for lexicographical ordering; or if I'm wrong, could you please explain how it does.

Comment: Indeed.  For example, the following sequence IS lexicographically ordered, but still fails the check: `A = numpy.array([1,2,3],[2,1,1],[3,0,0])`.  I think the OP will need to roll his own test function.

Answer (score 1):

To have an `issorted` predicate you need a well defined sort, or at least a clear method of comparing items.

To follow on my question about the nature of your data.  It sounds as though you have something like this:

```
In [130]: x=[[1,3],[3,4],[1,2],[3,1],[0,2],[6,5]]
In [131]: x1=[np.array(i).reshape(1,2) for i in x]
In [132]: x1
Out[132]: 
[array([[1, 3]]),
 array([[3, 4]]),
 array([[1, 2]]),
 array([[3, 1]]),
 array([[0, 2]]),
 array([[6, 5]])]
```

The Python sort is lexographic - that is, sort of the 1st element on the sublists, and then on the 2nd element.

```
In [137]: sorted(x)
Out[137]: [[0, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3], [3, 1], [3, 4], [6, 5]]
```

`numpy` sorts don't preserve the pairs - depending on the `axis` specification it sorts by column, or row (or flat).  But the `np.sort` doc does say that complex numbers are sorted lexographically:

```
In [157]: xj = np.dot(x,[1,1j])
In [158]: xj
Out[158]: array([ 1.+3.j,  3.+4.j,  1.+2.j,  3.+1.j,  0.+2.j,  6.+5.j])
In [159]: np.sort(xj)
Out[159]: array([ 0.+2.j,  1.+2.j,  1.+3.j,  3.+1.j,  3.+4.j,  6.+5.j])
```

This matches the Python list sort.

---

If my guess as to your data type is correct, a comparison based test would use something like:

```
In [167]: [i.__lt__(j) for i,j in zip(x[:-1],x[1:])]
Out[167]: [True, False, True, False, True]
In [168]: xs=sorted(x)
In [169]: [i.__lt__(j) for i,j in zip(xs[:-1],xs[1:])]
Out[169]: [True, True, True, True, True]
```

That also works for the complex array:

```
In [173]: xjs=np.sort(xj)
In [174]: [i.__lt__(j) for i,j in zip(xjs[:-1],xjs[1:])]
Out[174]: [True, True, True, True, True]
```

For large lists I'd try one of the `itertools` for short circuiting iteration.

But when applied to the (plain) array, it is clear that the question of whether it is sorted or not needs further specification.

```
In [172]: [i.__lt__(j) for i,j in zip(x1[:-1],x1[1:])]
Out[172]: 
[array([[ True,  True]], dtype=bool),
 array([[False, False]], dtype=bool),
 array([[ True, False]], dtype=bool),
 array([[False,  True]], dtype=bool),
 array([[ True,  True]], dtype=bool)]
```

---

By the way, a list of (2,1) arrays would look something like this:

```
[np.array(i).reshape(1,2) for i in x]

[array([[1, 3]]),
 array([[3, 4]]),
 array([[1, 2]]),
 array([[3, 1]]),
 array([[0, 2]]),
 array([[6, 5]])]
```

which if turned into an array would have a `(6,1,2)` shape.  Or did you want a `(6,2)` array?

```
In [179]: np.array(x)
Out[179]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [6, 5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy has **[lexsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html)**, but this does a sort, not a test of whether the data is sorted.  None-the-less, running it on sorted data is about twice as fast as unsorted.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def data(N):
    return np.random.randint(0,10,(N,2))

def get_sorted(x):
    return x[np.lexsort(x.T)]

x = data(5)
y  = get_sorted(x)

print x  # to verify lex sorting
print
print y
print

x = data(1000)
y  = get_sorted(x)

# to test the time for sorted vs unsorted data
print timeit.timeit("np.lexsort(x.T)", "from __main__ import np, x", number=1000)
print timeit.timeit("np.lexsort(y.T)", "from __main__ import np, y", number=1000)
```

And here are the results:

```
[[6 7]   # unsorted
 [4 3]
 [6 7]
 [9 2]
 [7 3]]

[[9 2]   # sorted by the second column first
 [4 3]
 [7 3]
 [6 7]
 [6 7]]

0.0788  # time to lex sort 1000x2 unsorted data values
0.0381  # time to lex sort 1000x2 pre-sorted data values
```

Note also that the speed of python vs numpy will depend on the list, because python can sometime **short-circuit** its tests.  So if you think that your list will generally be unsorted, a pure python solution could figure this out in the first few values, which could be much faster; whereas numpy solutions will generally work the the entire array.